# Python2.7 executes statements given as command resolve Unicode string incorrectly, but interactive prompt does well

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, unicode

In Python interactive prompt:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = u'中'
>>> s
u'\u4e2d'
>>> print s
中
```

I can get the Unicode string '中' printed correctly.
But when I do like this in Bash command line:
`python2 -c "s = u'中'; print(repr(s)); print(s)"`
the result of the command I get is

```
u'\xe4\xb8\xad'
ä¸­
```

My terminal character set encoding is 'UTF-8'. So, what's wrong with the command line statements of Python? Why it the command line statements can't print Unicode string properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting question. I try to dig in and conclude that it's the problem of how command line parameter of `-c` translated into source code in Python 2 interpreter.

It seems in Python 2 `s = u'中'` in command line parameter (of unicode shell) is translated somewhat like `s = u'\xe4\xb8\xad'`. As if it runs a script file with `latin1` encoding (such an extended ASCII). While in Python 3, it is translated somewhat like `s = u'\u4e2d'`, so it prints correctly. So, it's not the problem of bash or the terminal.

```
Interpreting source as utf-8:
    [73] [20] [3d] [20] [75] [27] [e4 b8 ad] [27]
    [s]  [ ]  [=]  [ ]  [u]  [']  [中]        [']

Interpreting source as latin-1:
    [73] [20] [3d] [20] [75] [27] [e4] [b8] [ad] [27]
    [s]  [ ]  [=]  [ ]  [u]  [']  [ä]  [¸]  [­]   [']
```

Try `python2` console:

```
>>> s = u'\xe4\xb8\xad'
>>> s
u'\xe4\xb8\xad'
>>> print s
ä¸­

>>> print u'\xe4'
ä
>>> print u'\xb8'
¸
>>> print u'\xad'
­
```

As I said, it is as if you write a source code, state it as `latin1` encoded, and run with `python2`. Try to save this into a file and run with `python2`:

```
# coding=latin1
s = u'中'
print repr(s)
print s
```

Output:

```
u'\xe4\xb8\xad'
ä¸­
```

That's my conclusion, it is the problem of how command line parameter of `-c` is "decoded" as source in Python 2, as if it's decoded by using `latin1`.

So, a hack for this is:

```
echo -e "# coding=utf8\ns = u'中'; print(repr(s)); print(s)" | python
```

**More readings**

- [Python 2 data model: string](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#index-20)
- [PEP 263 -- Defining Python Source Code Encodings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)
- [ISO/IEC 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Answer (score 1):

Unicode characters you enter in bash get passed in as UTF-8.

That means entering this in bash:

```
python2 -c "s = u'中'; print(repr(s)); print(s)"
```

Gets run as this code:

```
s = u'\xe4\xb8\xad';
print(repr(s)); 
print(s)
```

u'something' is a unicode literal, which does no UTF-8 decoding, but interprets the bytes as characters directly. u'\xe4\xb8\xad' is understood as the string of three distrinct characters E4, B8 and AD (ä, "cedilla" and "soft hyphen").

The reason it works from interactive prompt is that when you enter s = u'中', the interpreter passes it in directly as u'\u4e2d' without UTF-8 mangling it.

Comment: Yes, it works, but what I want to know is that why the result is different and the command line statements can't produce the correct result?

Comment: Interestingly python -c "s = u'\u4e2d'; print repr(s); print s" works as well, I wonder what the issue is with s = u'中' ...

Comment: \xe4\xb8\xad is the UTF-8 encoding of 中, so it looks like bash is already utf-8 encoding it

Comment: Maybe there is something related to the encoding Bash resolve Unicode arguments with. I think.

Comment: Researched a bit more and updated my answer. Result of experimenting and reading https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html